# How Do I Add 2 Hours from Formatted Time

Tags: mysql

I need to know how to add 2 hours to the below 'Completed' timestamp.

Here is the Select statement

```
    Select Tsk.task_id,Tsk.org_id,Tsk.completed,Tsk.assgn_acct_id,name 
    FROM tdstelecom.tasks As Tsk
    WHERE Tsk.task_id = '11094836'
    AND DATE(Tsk.completed) < CURDATE() AND DATE(Tsk.completed) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE
    (),INTERVAL 180 DAY)
```

Here are the results: 2012-08-22 14:18:14

Desired results: 2012-08-22 16:18:14

Comment: @gSaenz title says SQL server but curdate is MySql so the title is wrong

Comment: @Marc missed that, it also said subtract, but sample showed add

Comment: Quite confusing, at least it's not a big difference. It must be add 2 hours in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Your tag says mySQL, use the [subtime(exp1,exp2)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime) function `SUBTIME(Tsk.completed, '02:00:00.000000')` in your select should do the trick.

Comment: your title says subtract but your body says add, use `addtime()` or `subtime()` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Tsk.completed+interval 2 hour,Tsk.assgn_acct_id,name 
FROM tdstelecom.tasks As Tsk
WHERE Tsk.task_id = '11094836'
AND DATE(Tsk.completed) < CURDATE() AND DATE(Tsk.completed) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE
(),INTERVAL 180 DAY)
```